# How to structure API test with dynamic response based on combination of 3 optional fields?

Tags: json, rest, api, soap, web-api-testing

A service has different and dynamic responses based on what combination of 3 optional fields are sent in a request it receives, how do you structure testing this service?

Comment: It will be great if more specific next time

Comment: Need more details such as: What language it is in? Are you are using any frameworks? What type of test you would like (ie unit test, load test)? And if possible a code snippet of what you would like to test.

Comment: this is exact question that interviewer  asked, i was trying to break down the question to get more details but thats all i got . i guess question itself is confusing ...i thought i would ask maybe someone have met this kind of question before